# Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}]."

Tags: laravel-5.7

in new to laravel and Im trying to set up an edit blade using  resource controller .  (  using laravel 5.7) but it is throwing an error like this

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: home.hotels.update] [URI: home/hotels/{hotel}]. (View: C:\xamp\....\.....\edit.blade.php)
```

Please note: 
  when i hover over edit button it is correctly pointing to the id's and 
  when i tries to echo a fieldname inside my  "edit function"in controller  it returns the correct page but "blank" . can some one tell me wher this error comming from and if possible how to fix this

code in my index blade ( part relating to the edit)

```
@foreach($hotels as $c)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$c->hotelid}}</td> 
        <td>{{$c->hotelname}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->city}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->location}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->singleroom}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->doubleroom}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->deluxroom}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->deluxdouble}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->superiorsuit}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{route('home.hotels.edit',$c->id)}}"class="btn btn-info"  >Update </a>
```

my edit blade
im passing the entries like this

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('home.hotels.update',$hotels->id)}}"> 
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-6">Hotel ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="hotelid" class="form-control" value="{{$hotels->hotelid}}"> </div>
        </div>
   .........  rest of the  input fields follows........
```

controller functions

```
public function index()
{
    $arr['hotels']=hotels::all();
    return view('admin.hotels.index')->with($arr);
}
```

my update function also has the same code  as store ------

```
public function store(Request $request, hotels $hotels)
{
    $hotels->hotelid=$request->hotelid;
    $hotels->hotelname=$request->hotelname;
    ...........other fields.................. 
    $hotels->save();
    return redirect('home/hotels');
}

public function edit(hotels $hotels )
{

    $arr['hotels'] = $hotels;
    return view('admin.hotels.edit')->with($arr);

}
```

and my routes

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('home/users', 'Admin\UsersController',['as'=>'home']);
Route::resource('home/hotels', 'Admin\HotelsController',['as'=>'home']);
```